# Is it possible to inject code into stack on x86-64

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

My system is a x86-64 Linux, and I try to execute the code in the stack or data segment on the system. In detail, I first placed a piece of binary instructions into an integer array(I tried to place the array in either stack or data segment) , then replaced normal function return address with the array address. Every time, I got segmentation fault.

My question is, does x86-64 has some segmentation protection mechanism to stop the execution behavior in either stack or data segment? If it is true, does it means code injection through buffer overflow is totally stopped in x86-64 architecture?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nx-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all modern general purpose architectures have a way to prevent you from executing certain memory regions. It depends on the operating system if the operating system uses those facilities. Linux disables execution on the stack and most data on the architectures where it's easy to do. x86_64 is one of those.